# How to find if a group is internal or external in apex

Tags: apex, soql, public-group

Is there a way to find out if a group is of external users only. I know you can do something like this:

```
select id,name,portaltype from userrole where id = 'name of the relatedid of the group'
```

Using the type field under group does not give this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about roles, then you can look at the userrole.portaltype field; if this == "None", then the role is internal; otherwise it is external. (You can also look at the userrole.portalrole field; if this == null, then the role is internal.)

If you are talking about groups, then you can run this query to find groups with external members:

```
SELECT Group.DeveloperName FROM GroupMember  
WHERE UserOrGroupId IN 
        (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true AND Profile.UserType NOT IN ('Standard', 'CSNOnly'))
```

You may find other user types that qualify as "internal" - and may have to adjust this query.

Comment: Thanks John. I modified it a little like you said to get what I wanted. SELECT id,RelatedId,DeveloperName,Name,Type FROM Group WHERE relatedid IN (SELECT id FROM Userrole WHERE PortalType = 'Partner').